# Barcode scanner SDK

Tags: barcode, sdk

I´m searching for a good barcode scanner SDK.

We tried out quagga(open source) but it was to slow for what we need. We also tried Scandit and liked it a lot but its to expensive for our budget.

We need good performance with high scan speed at a low as possible price. Anyone has any recommendations, best if its supported by data we can use to compare it.

We have a lot of different codes so we need 1D and 2D support.
We start the scanner over a web-client (no Android/iOS).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be worth taking a look at https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/21/an-opencv-barcode-and-qr-code-scanner-with-zbar/

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, i will try it out.

Comment: If it works for you let me know & I will convert it to a proper  answer. _A bit pushed for time ATM_

Answer (score 1):

The company I work for has the [LEADTOOLS Barcode Pro Developer Toolkit](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/barcode-pro), which supports over 100 different 1D and 2D barcode types and sub-types.

Pricing starts at $1,295 for a one-programmer license, and you can get detailed cost information by contacting sales@leadtools.com with your actual requirements and deployment needs.

You can try the free evaluation edition from [this page](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=main#main), which comes with free technical support through email and online chat.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the [barKoder Barcode Scanner SDK](https://barkoder.com/). Relatively new on the market but blowing competition out in terms of performance. Price is quite good also! It supports almost all 1D & 2D barcode types and has native, Flutter, React versions.